# Percent revenue increase since previous year per country

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the percentage increase revenue since last year, per country.

```
create table Customer
(
customer_mail_address   varchar(255) not null,
lastname                varchar(50) not null,
firstname               varchar(50) not null,
payment_method          varchar(10) not null,
payment_card_number     varchar(30) not null,
contract_type           varchar(20) not null,
subscription_start      date        not null,
subscription_end        date                ,
user_name               varchar(30) not null,
password                varchar(50) not null,
country_name            varchar(50) not null,
gender                  char(1)             ,
birth_date              date                ,

constraint pk_Customer primary key(customer_mail_address),
constraint fk_Customer1 foreign key(country_name) references Country(country_name) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
constraint fk_Customer2 foreign key(contract_type) references Contract(contract_type) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
constraint fk_Customer3 foreign key(payment_method) references Payment(payment_method) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
constraint chk_Customer1 check(subscription_start < subscription_end),
constraint uc_Customer unique(user_name),
constraint chk_Customer2 check(len([password]) >= 8 AND [password] like '%[0-9]%'),
constraint chk_Customer3 check(birth_date < subscription_start),
constraint chk_Customer4 check(user_name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%') 
)


create table Watchhistory
(
movie_id                integer     not null,
customer_mail_address   varchar(255)not null,
watch_date              date        not null,
price                   numeric(5,2)not null,
invoiced                bit         not null,

constraint pk_Watchhistory primary key(movie_id, customer_mail_address, watch_date),
constraint fk_Watchhistory1 foreign key(movie_id) references Movie(movie_id),
constraint fk_Watchhistory2 foreign key(customer_mail_address) references Customer(customer_mail_address) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

These two tables are what I use to calculate this. I tried a lot of stuff but nothing really did the trick. This is what I have now to calculate the revenue for each year per country but not the percentage increase per country.

```
CREATE VIEW OmzetStijgingDalingPerLand AS
SELECT DATEPART(yy,watch_date) as [jaar], country_name, SUM(price) AS [omzet]
FROM Watchhistory w
INNER JOIN Customer c ON w.customer_mail_address = c.customer_mail_address
GROUP BY DATEPART(yy,watch_date), country_name
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but plus one for showing what you've tried and asking clearly and concisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should check out `LAG`. You should also definitely consider a different PK on the `Customer` table, as `customer_mail_address` is a poor choice for both a Primary Key and a Clustered Index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is described in article mentioned before, LAG function is the key

```
SELECT jaar,
 country_name,
 omzet,
 omzet / LAG(omzet, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY jaar) AS increase_percent
FROM OmzetStijgingDalingPerLand
```